# Why does my laptop's performance drop for a few minutes when connecting it to power?

Tags: laptop, performance, battery

I have a very peculiar problem with my laptop. When my laptop battery is low and I connect it to power, the performance drops extremely, to the point where it becomes impossible to use. Windows take upwards of 30 seconds to display, keystrokes have extreme delay, etc...

This behavior persists for several minutes, then the performance returns to normal. When the power cable is pulled, the performance also immediately returns to normal. It only occurs when the battery power is low - if the cable is inserted when the batters has more than ~25% charge, the performance remains normal. This behavior is 100% reproducible.

Comment: Could be high current drawn by charging the battery causing a power regulator or something to get hot and cause some level of thermal throttling. Solution would be to not let it get that low, deep cycling lithium cells isn't that great for them.

Comment: The idea posted above is generally true . What you might try is a vanilla battery reset. Charge to Full. Unplug and let run down to about zero (machine turns off so make sure nothing is running. Charge to Full, and restart the computer. Does the battery now work correctly?

Comment: does the laptop have a "dedicated" GPU (e.g. AMD or nVidia)? Hypothesis: the laptop may be running on the cpu-based gpu and then switching to the dedicated gpu (higher-performance power plan) when plugged and {bad magic} is happening.

Comment: @Yorik Then why does it not have these problems when the batters is higher?

Comment: Some sort of ping-pong effect related to estimated battery life and the handover between iGPU and GPU?

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly a guess but it could be high current drawn by charging the battery causing a power regulator or something to get hot and cause some level of thermal throttling. The solution would be to not let it get that low, or to simply accept the temporary loss of responsiveness.

It would not be too surprising for a laptop to have a thermal sensor in amongst the charging circuitry that would be triggering BD PROCHOT and limiting processor performance. It might be there in an attempt to prevent battery overheating by limiting the amount of heat added by the CPU on top of other sources. It could also be the sudden high flow of current into a depleted battery causes the battery to heat up and warm the rest of the system and trigger thermal limits that way.

You can use a tool such as [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) and watch all your thermal sensors when charging from <25%. If a sensor shows surprisingly high temperature or your CPU locks to 400 or 800MHz then you are probably seeing some part of the system triggering thermal throttling.

Deep cycling lithium cells isn't that great for them.